# How to list exported functions in a shared lib on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker

I have just built a shared lib on Ubuntu, and when I attempt to use the function, the application that loads the library is reporting 'xxx' symbol not found.

I want to check (i.e. list) the functions that are exported by my library so I can investigate this issue further.

Relevant details:

OS: Ubuntu 9.10
  compiler: gcc 4.4.1
  linker: GNU ld 2.20

Answer (score 29):

Try the nm utility.

> GNU nm lists the symbols from object
>   files objfile.... If no object files
>   are listed as arguments, nm assumes
>   the file a.out. [[reference]](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm)

Comment: **nm -C --defined-only -g libXXX.so** for C++

Comment: Thanks for that. It appears my symbol is exported, but undefined (it has a 'U' next to the function name). How can a function be exported and yet be undefined (IIRC, a linker option prevents this kind of absurbity). More importantly, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: By "Fixing it", I mean how can I ensure that my functions are exported AND DEFINED in the shared library?

Comment: Could it be that the undefined symbol is contained in another shared object? Check out Void's advice.

Comment: Were you able to find the root cause for your problem? I am trying to link a FORTRAN-based library and it is showing a function as undefined in the output shared library

Answer (score 24):

```
nm -D -C -g <library>
```

works well too.

Comment: For _exported_ functions add `--defined-only` option, otherwise this way you'll get imports too. Also, to get only _functions_ and not e.g. something like `_edata`, you should look for the symbols with `T` or `t` in the second column. So, something like this: `nm -DCg --defined-only $MY_LIB | grep '^[0-9a-f]\+ [Tt] '`

Answer (score 2):

Is your shared library in the library load path or in the application's run-time search path?  It sounds like the dynamic linker can't find your library.  Try running [`ldd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) on your application to see if the library can be found at run-time, *e.g.*:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/less
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x0072a000)
    libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00c68000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0x007c7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0x00286000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x002a1000)
```

See the [ld.so(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) man page for additional details on library search paths.